# Как сделать картинку кликабельной в Android?

Tags: java, android

Как сделать картинку кликабельной в Android?

Comment: Android Studio - это всего лишь инструмент для разработки (IDE). Ничего особенного в установке изображения именно используя для разработки Android Studio нет.

Comment: @metalurgus понял)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Установите картинку в `ImageView`, и установите ему `OnClickListener`. `OnClickListener` можно установить любому `View`

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас попробую. Спасибо!

Comment: Возможно еще стоит добавить `android:clickable="true"`

Comment: @xAqweRx, нет, не стоит.

Answer (score 0):

Можно указать прямую ссылку на метод из активити

```
android:onClick = метод
```